# Column dependent on serial column in posgresql

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, sql-insert, series

I am using Java's prepared statements to commit insert statements. I have two columns that I care about:

```
create table(a serial, b integer)
```

I want to insert using generate_series(1, 10000)

However, I want to set integer

```
B = A mod 10
```

Is there an SQL to do this? I want to achieve this in one shot so I can give Java's prepared statement one string.

e.g. `INSERT INTO my_table values (generate_series(1,100000), =mod 10 of whatever was generated in the previous column)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
insert into t (b)
    select val % 10
    from generate_series(1, 10000, 1) gs(val)
    order by gs.val;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=18e2a688ba2290b7733d22793a4cb055) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: I tried what you did with generate_series(1,10), it produces something like this: (3,2) , (4,3) (11, 8)... not sure how it generated them in that order. Say we are doing mod 3, I want the insert to generate all column a, and set all column b to be the mod3 of whatever was generated in column a, e.g. (0, 0) (1, 1) , (2, 2) (3,0) (4, 1) (5, 2) ...

Comment: @Hadi . . . I would expect the values to be in order, even without an `order by`.  But it is more proper to include the `order by`.

Answer (score 0):

Your create table t(a serial, b integer). This will a sequence named t_a_seq. You can 'override' the the automatic generation of column a, using nextval, currval for that sequence. So:

```
create table t( a serial, b integer);
-- generates sequence t_a_seq;

insert into t (a,b)
    select nextval('t_a_seq'::regclass), currval('t_a_seq'::regclass) % 3
    from generate_series(1, 10000, 1) gs(val)
 ;
```

NOT highly recommended but it gets the job done.